# Check Panel to enable/disable visibility

Tags: asp.net

This just feels "hacky" to me in terms of having to do both enable/disable for both of these.  Since one of them could already have been turned "on" I need to turn them back off or on again.  I feel as though I can dodge one of the checks somehow:

```
private void SetPanels()
{
    if(userIsLoggedIn)
    {
        pnlAuthed.Visible = true;
        pnlNotAuthed.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pnlSignUpForm_NotAuthed.Visible = true;
        pnlSignUpForm_Authed.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
    pnlAuthed.Visible = userIsLoggedIn;
    pnlNotAuthed.Visible = !userIsLoggedIn;

    pnlSignUpForm_NotAuthed.Visible = !userIsLoggedIn;
    pnlSignUpForm_Authed.Visible = userIsLoggedIn;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are basically re-writing what the standard asp.net [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control can do declaratively:

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
     Please log in for personalized information.
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
     Thanks for logging in 
     <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: sorry but I don't want to use a view like that.  We'll be moving to MVC soon and I don't want to use many asp.net controls.

Comment: Then in that case you'll be rolling your own anyway -- `asp:Panel` is an ASP.NET WebForms control. BTW, if everything you do is client-side (your view files), many of the WebForms controls will continue to work in a MVC.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Dan Diplo's [LoginView answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590859/check-panel-to-enable-disable-visibility/1590941#1590941), you may want to consider the [MultiView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) control in a more generalized (IE, not specifically login-related) case. The MultiView contains a set of one or more mutually-exclusive Views (similar to Panels), which

The MultiView is relatively easy to set up declaratively:

```
<asp:MultiView runat="server" id="pageMultiView" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View runat="server" id="view1">
        <!-- your 1st view content here! -->
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View runat="server" id="view2">
        <!-- your 2nd view content here! -->
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

In code, you switch views like so:

```
pageMultiView.SetActiveView(view1);
```

And thus, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be snarky, but for starters, couldn't you shorten it to:

```
pnlUpdate.Visible = showUpdate;
divSignUp.Visible = showSignUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetPanels()
{
    pnlAuthed.Visible = userIsLoggedIn;
    pnlNotAuthed.Visible = !pnlAuthed.Visible;
}
```